# react-native [Expo]: can I increase PanResponder's input sampling rate?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drawing, react-native-svg, panresponder

I am currently implementing a [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) based drawing input for my Expo application (it is a slight modification of this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633579/expo-react-native-draw-line-between-coordinates-on-two-type-of-views)). I use a `PanResponder` to register move events and create different paths that I then display as multiple `Polyline` elements while the user draws on the view like so:

```js
const GesturePath: React.FC<GesturePathProps> = ({
  paths,
  color,
  width,
  height,
  strokeWidth,
}) => {
  return (
    <Svg height='100%' width='100%' viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
      {paths.map((path) => (
        <Polyline
          key={path.id}
          points={path.points.map((p) => `${p.x},${p.y}`).join(" ")}
          fill='none'
          stroke={color}
          strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
        />
      ))}
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

Unfortunately, the lines I produce are extremely rough and jagged and I believe the `PanResponder.onPanResponderMove` handler is fired too infrequently for my needs (on average it is called every 50ms on the Android Pixel 4 emulator and I'm not sure if I can expect more from a real device).

Maybe there is better candidate than PanResponder for handling gestures in my use case?

I have implemented a smoothing function (based on this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324313/svg-smooth-freehand-drawing)) that behaves correctly but since the points are so distant from each other the user's input gets noticeably distorted.

Here's an example without smoothing:

[image: SVG drawing example]

Below my GestureHandler implementation:

```js
const GestureRecorder: React.FC<GestureRecorderProps> = ({ addPath }) => {
  const buffRef = useRef<Position[]>([]);
  const pathRef = useRef<Position[]>([]);
  const timeRef = useRef<number>(Date.now());
  const pathIdRef = useRef<number>(0);

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

      onPanResponderMove: (event) => {
        // workaround for release event
        // not working consistently on android
        if (Date.now() - timeRef.current > RELEASE_TIME) {
          pathIdRef.current += 1;
          pathRef.current = [];
          buffRef.current = [];
        }
        timeRef.current = Date.now();

        pathRef.current.push({
          x: event.nativeEvent.locationX,
          y: event.nativeEvent.locationY,
        });

        addPath({
          points: calculateSmoothedPath(event),
          id: pathIdRef.current,
        });
      },

      // not working on Android
      // release event is not consistent
      // onPanResponderRelease: () => {
      // pathIdRef.current += 1;
      // pathRef.current = [];
      // buffRef.current = [];
      // },
    })
  ).current;

  const calculateSmoothedPath = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => { 
    // implementation
    // ...
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324313/svg-smooth-freehand-drawing
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      collapsable={false}
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}
    />
  );
};
```

### Side Note

I have not found any documentation on PanResponder suggesting that a sample rate configuration option exists so I am totally open to alternatives (even dropping the PanResponder + native SVG method entirely) as long as I don't have to eject the expo project and I can have control over the layout (I don't want to use external components that come with specific UIs).

I have tried using the [expo-pixi](https://github.com/expo/expo-pixi) library (specifically the `Sketch` component), but the repository seems not to be mantained anymore and the expo client crashes consistently when using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying different solutions after I posted the question and I have ended up changing my `GestureHandler` implementation slightly.
I am now using `PanGestureHandler` from [react-native-gesture-handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/) instead of `PanResponder`.
This component lets the user specify a `minDist` prop for tweaking activation, here is the description from the docs:

> Minimum distance the finger (or multiple finger) need to travel before the handler activates. Expressed in points.

Below the new implementation:

```
<PanGestureHandler
  minDist={1}
  onGestureEvent={(e) => {
    // same code from the previous onPanResponderMove
  }
>
  <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} collapsable={false} />
</PanGestureHandler>
```

I had also overestimated my GPU capabilities while running the emulator, after building an APK and testing on a real device I realized the drawing input behaves much more fluidly.